# Fubini Theorem. How it can be?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

How this equality is true:

$\left ( \int\limits_{-a}^a e^{-x^2} dx \right )\cdot \left ( \int\limits_{-a}^a e^{-y^2} dy \right )=\int\limits_{-a}^a \int\limits_{-a}^a e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dx\,dy$

For example:

$\left ( \int\limits_{-b}^b e^{-x^2} dx \right )\cdot \left ( \int\limits_{-a}^a e^{3x-y^2} dy \right )=\int\limits_{-a}^a \int\limits_{-b}^b e^{-(x^2+y^2)+3x}\,dx\,dy$

is also true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is fine, the second one doesn't even make sense ($x$ is used as a parameter to the equation (in the $y$-integral) and as a variable of integration at the same time.)
The first one works because $\int_{-a}^a e^{-x^2} dx$ is a constant (with respect to $y$, or anything else except for $a$) as well as $e^{-y^2}$ with respect to $x$ (or anything except for $y$) so
$$\int_{-a}^a e^{-x^2} dx \int_{-a}^a e^{-y^2} dy = \int_{-a}^a \underbrace{\int_{-a}^a e^{-x^2} dx}_{\text{const w.r.t. } y} e^{-y^2} dy = \int_{-a}^a \int_{-a}^a e^{-x^2} \underbrace{e^{-y^2}}_{\text{const w.r.t. }x} dx dy = \iint e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} dx dy$$

Comment: I get it. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help you there :)

Comment: @Editor: The point is not that $\int_{-a}^a e^{-y^2} dy$ is a constant only dependent on $a$, but rather that the $e^{-y^2}$ is a constant wrt $x$ so we can "pull" it into the inner integral. Also note that the integral IS a constant, with respect to anything except for $a$, since it includes no further parameters.